# can I create list of buttons for Android app using listview or do I need to use recyclerview?

Tags: android

I was wondering if I want to create a simple list of buttons, a recycler view will be needed or if I can make do with a listview.  Thank you

Comment: Both will work... Do you have a specific issue with them?

Comment: I wanted to find the simpler method so that I don't have to build an adapter and viewHolder, which I believe can be achieved by using listview?

Comment: Listview also uses an adapter

Comment: I see. Would the buttons need to be nested in a TextView or can they be used directly, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to create the buttons and add them the view. **I strongly recommend you to not do it** the following example is for demonstratiom purpose:

```
onCreate...
LinearLayout root = findViewBy...
for (item: dataList) {
    Button btn = newn Button(this);
    btn.setText(item.text);
    root.addView(btn);
}
```

In this example Im using a linear with vertical orientation, that should be inside a scrollview.

**That is bad** because every view is in memory at the same time. If you have just 2 or 3 buttons then there is no problem but if the number raise to hundreds then there will be memory usage problems.

This is why ListView got deprecated, because every row was rendered. Large data set made the UI slow. Instead RecyclerView literally recyle the views as the name implies. In memory there is only the view on the screen and a bit extra, so when a view leaves the window is available to be reused by the incoming row.

By the comments I can see you are also confused with views and viewgroups. A TextView is a View it can not have another View inside. If you only need to have a click, then TextViews can use a setOnClickListener, other is the case if you need the appearance of a button. Anyway, when you create an adapter you can add any layout you want.

Answer (score 1):

A list of buttons can be achieved in both the ways. But ListView is outdated. So better use RecyclerView